# Alternative to multiple iterations of 'cut'

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to filter information out of a file - it's organized by column, and I haven't found a better way to get what I want than the following:

```
less $file | cut -d':' -f6 | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d '#' -f1
```

Is there an alternative to spamming 'cut'? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are alternatives, for example, `awk`, maybe if you put an example input someone will able to help you with that.

Comment: Please provide sample input and out

Comment: Sure it's ugly, but is it really that inefficient that you wouldn't want to do it.  Cut is a stream filter so each instance would be pretty lightweight.

Comment: @mykel fair enough. I suppose I'm looking for an elegant solution, but this does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `less` here; it's just a heavier version of `cat` in a pipeline. Either use `cat "$file" | cut -d':' -f6 | ...` or, better yet, `cut -d':' -f6 "$file" | ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, filtering strings is best done by regular expressions. However, for your particular example you can translate each `cut` into one of 2 simple `awk`
equivalents as follows. Either of these:

```
awk '{FS=":";$0=$0; FS=" ";$0=$6; FS="#";$0=$3; print $1}' $file

awk '{split($0,a,":"); split(a[6],b,/ +/); split(b[3],c,"#"); print c[1]}' $file
```

The first technique converts "cut -dx -fy" into "FS=x; set $0 to input; result is $y". FS is the field separator.

The 2nd converts it into "split(input,output,x), result is output[y]".
I'm not sure how cut handles spaces as a delimiter, so I used a regular expression `/ +/` which matches many spaces as one. Use `" "` if to split on a single space.